# Вывести новые данные записанные в базу не обновляя страницы

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, клиент-сервер, comet

Необходимо выводить новые данные записанные в базу не обновляя страницы.
Есть два хороших по-моему мнению примера данной реализации:

- vk (получение нового сообщения)
- gmail (получение нового письма)

Я пока вижу только такой "унылый" способ это делать.
jquery(ajax, post) обновляемый счетчиком setinterval/,

```
$.post(
 "/ajaxtest.php",
 {
  param1: "param1",
  param2: 2
 },
 onAjaxSuccess
);

function onAjaxSuccess(data)
{
 // Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и выводим их на экран.
 alert(data);
}
```

и это все обернуть в счетчик к примеру каждый 5 минут.

Или создать **cron** на сервере с расписанием и каждые 5 минут обращаться к скрипту.php

но мне кажется, есть более интересные и правильные решения, может кто-то сталкивался с подобным, помогите пожалуйста, если честно не знаю как еще это можно реализовать, очень интересно.
Спасибо, за внимание!

Comment: вы как будто открыли дверь в параллельный мир, никогда про это не слышал, спасибо большое, обязательно ознакомлюсь!) Исчерпывающе!

Comment: `VK` & `GMail` юзают длинные опросы (да, да, вечный цикл через `setTimeout`). И даже для новых браузеров не кидают `WebSocket`, только что проверил.

Comment: Тогда прошу прощения за выражение ***два хороших по-моему мнению примера***, я был не прав! vk и settimeout?! вот это поворот)))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41274/discussion-between-other-and-).

Comment: @Teem, вынес ответ в ответ, его можно принять если он вам подходит (галочка под ретингом ответа).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что необходимые вам технологии, когда сервер должен отправлять какие-то данные на браузер, принято объединять термином [Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) (хотя и не всегда это теоретически верно), и при желании разобраться лучше гуглить стоит по нему.

Основных современных способа реализации существует три:

**[1. Длинные опросы (long-polling).](http://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-longpoll)**
Да, можно делать просто аякс-запрос по таймеру (это принято называть short-polling). У short-polling есть проблемы - не моментальное время отклика (время между тиками таймера), значительная нагрузка на сеть. Да и серверу приходится обрабатывать множество мусорных запросов.

Поэтому чаще используется немного усовершенствованный механизм, так называемый long-polling.
  Разница в том, что запрос не отправляется каждые n секунд. Он отправляется и висит, пока не отвалится или не получит ответ. И когда отвалится, отправляется новый запрос.

Лонг-поллинг - самый распространенный способ. Железобетонный, используется когда нужна хорошая кроссбраузерность. Те же `gmail` и `vk` использует его. Но постепенно он морально устаревает.

**[2. Server-sent events.](http://learn.javascript.ru/server-sent-events)**
Это браузерное API позволяющее получать события от сервера по `HTTP`. Используется реже сокетов и поллинга, потому что является неким промежуточным вариантом. Поллинг кроссбраузернее, сокеты - удобнее.

**[3. Вебсокеты.](http://learn.javascript.ru/websockets)**
Полноценный отдельный протокол для двусторонней клиент-серверной связи. То есть для таких задач специально созданный, и следовательно гораздо удобнее чем `HTTP`.   По `HTTP` происходит только первый запрос, хендшейк. Новые проекты обычно пишутся на сокетах, потому что их поддерживают все современные браузеры, включая ie с десятки и мобильные.

Comment: `висит пока не отвалится` - а сервак не повиснет от кучи запросов?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, разумеется сервак должен поддерживать возможность держать кучу таких запросов. Но в большинстве случаев это проще чем "каждые n секунд новый отправлять", в том числе с т.з. нагрузки. Про то, что этот способ в принципе ок - говорит уже то что он некоторое время использовался примерно везде.